# Replace enum value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi guys this is probably something really simple to do but am at my wits end! I have a website with a form that enters values into a mysql database so in my table I have enum fields '1','2','3','4' that are the values for Mr, Miss, Mrs, Ms, Dr and another for sex enum vales 'm','f' that are Male and Female.

Now the problem is this how do I replace  '1' for Mr and 'm' for Male when I echo them out on one of my other pages!

Here is some code to help!

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMembers WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        $title = $row["title"];
        $firstname = $row["firstname"];
        $lastname = $row["lastname"];
        $gender = $row["gender"];
    }
```

And I echo out here:

```
     if ($myvar == "yes") 
        {
        $myvar = "http://www.somesite.com/public/postlead.php?field1=' . $title . '&field14=' . $gender . '&field2=' . $firstname . '&field3=' . $lastname . '';
        } else {
          $myvar = '';
        }
```

Many thanks in advance all

Comment: I think your DB design is flawed and I would change the schema - As you highlight - enums are not good for this type of data storage - I would change the fields to `INT` and create lookup tables

Answer (score 3):

You could use SELECT...CASE

```
 SELECT CASE gender 
  WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female'
  WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male'
 END as gender_word , other_fields_here 
from myMembers WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think the DB schema should be fixed this is a hack IMHO :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try it using `case`,

```
SELECT (CASE gender WHEN 'Male' THEN 'M' END) as `Gender`,
       (CASE title WHEN 'Mr' THEN 1 END) as `Title`
FROM ....
```

Comment: I think the DB schema should be fixed this is a hack IMHO :-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish in some point I agree. I usually don't use `enum` hehe

Comment: I considered downvoting yours and sel's answer but they are not wrong :-) Hopefully the OP will take the schema change hint